# Is there any closed form solution for $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{2^{n-i}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{2^{n-i}}$ as a sum. Is there a closed solution for this sum?

My try:

It is not geometric series because:

$$
\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}= \frac{2^{2^{n-k-1}}}{2^{2^{n-k}}}
$$
is not a constant?

Comment: you can't, because it's false. you probably mean product, in which case you sum the exponents

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I revised it.

Comment: @mathworker21:I revised it.

Comment: The answer is “no, there is no closed formula.”

Comment: It might help to re-index: $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{2^{n-i}}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{2^{i}}$$

Comment: This sequence of sums, starting at $n=1$, appears in the OEIS as [A060803](https://oeis.org/A060803).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, this is not true.

If you consider the first terms of the sequence
$$\{2,6,22,278,65814,4295033110,18446744078004584726\}$$ they correspond to sequence $A060803$ at $OEIS$ (see [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+6%2C+22%2C+278%2C+65814%2C+4295033110%2C+18446744078004584726&sort=&language=&go=Search)) and,  for once, they do not propose ny approximation or asymptotics.

A quick plot shows that more or less
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{2^{n-i}}$$ varies as
$$\log_2(\log_2(S_n))=a+ b n$$ A quick and dirty linear regression work for $1 \leq n \leq 30$ (overflow above since $S_{30} \approx 2.0487\times 10^{161614248}$) gives with $R^2=0.999985$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -0.931993 & 0.0258745 & \{-0.985083,-0.878902\} \\
 b & +0.996793 & 0.0014575 & \{+0.993802,+0.999783\} \\
\end{array}$$

However, back to the computed values, it is quite bad since, rounding the first terms, they would be
$$\{2,4,18,318,98435,9207133935,76558870207093342208\}$$